# Python raw_input() exploit to Remote Code Execution

Tags: python, exploit

I am looking for a way to use a raw_input() prompt to execute code of another object to ensure I do this in a secure way.

I have two classes, the 1st has a method i am not supposed to call, neither from outside, nor from inside ; the 2nd has a method to parse a user's request built this way : "method-to-call arg1 arg2 ...".
For example : "add 5 3". And the method "do_add" shall be called with 5 and 3 as arguments.

```
class Obj1 :

    # ...

    def do_forbidden(self) :
        # Not supposed to execute

    # ...

class Obj2 :

    # ...

    def process_cmd(self, cmd) :
        words = cmd.split()
        if len(words) > 0 :
            mthdname = 'do_' + words[ 0 ]
            args = words[1:]

            if hasattr(self, mthdname):
                mthd = getattr(self, mthdname)
                mthd(*args)

    # ...
```

Then :

```
obj1 = Obj1()
obj2 = Obj2()
# ...
cmd = raw_input("Command : ")
obj2.process_cmd(cmd)
```

Here, is there a way to type something that can execute "do_forbidden()" from obj1? And does input() instead of raw_input() makes a difference?

If an exploit is actually possible, an attacker can 'guess' one of the methods' name to execute it, then is the prefix 'do_' a good protection?

Comment: I am using Python 2.6, if this can be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to exploit this. Unless of course one of the `do_` methods has some other vulnerability. You can't execute a method not defined on the same object as `process_cmd` is called from.

`input` would be a totally different thing, that alows you execute about anything you want.

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure there is not a weird way to perform something such as a buffer overflow or any other weird thing?

Comment: For input(), I guess keeping raw_input() is a good idea then!

Comment: Buffer overflows are usually a result of wrong memory allocation. As you don't do that manually in Python it's very unlikely to produce one (mayby in a C extension, yes, or through the ctypes module...)